# How to showing text inside recycleview without restarting the app?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

My problem is I can not add text inside of recycleview  after pressing the OK button unless i restart the app , every time I am writing a word inside of dialog box then press OK but the word does not appear inside of recycleview only after restart the app ,I want to type the word and then press the OK button Then the word appears directly inside the recycleview

[image]

// class Tab1 :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.sql.language.SQLite;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import static android.R.attr.fragment;
import static com.example.chirag.slidingtabsusingviewpager.R.id.parent;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link Tab1.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link Tab1#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */

public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
    @Inject
    Context mContext_;
    View rootView;

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    Context context;
    SimpleAdapter adapter;// = new SimpleAdapter(generateSimpleList());
    RecyclerView recyclerView ;//= (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.simple_recyclerview);

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private List<Organization>organizationList;
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private static Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater2;
    ViewGroup Container = null;
    View vr;

    public Tab1(){
    // Required empty public constructor
    //   test ();
     //context = getContext();
      Organization organization = new Organization();
       organizationList = SQLite.select().from(Organization.class).queryList();
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment Tab1.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters


    public static Tab1 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Tab1 fragment = new Tab1();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container,false);
        vr = view;//inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container,false);
        initViews();
        showInputDialog();
       return view;
    }




    private void initViews(){
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(generateSimpleList());
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)vr.findViewById(R.id.simple_recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString() + "must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */


    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }


private List<SimpleViewModel> generateSimpleList(){
      List<SimpleViewModel>simpleViewModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i<organizationList.size(); i++){
           simpleViewModelList.add(new SimpleViewModel(String.format(Locale.US,organizationList.get(i).getName().toString(),""+organizationList.get(i).getName().toString())));
            // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"as"+ organizationList.get(i).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
        return simpleViewModelList;
    }

    protected void showInputDialog(){
       LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
       //LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext().getApplicationContext());
       final View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.input_dialog, null);
       AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
       alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);
       final EditText editText = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        // final EditText editText = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        // setup a dialog window
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
        Organization organization = new Organization();
        organization.setId(organizationList.size()+1);
        organization.setName(editText.getText().toString());
        organization.save();
        //initViews();
        }}).setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        //create an alert dialog
        AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alert.show();
        /*
        AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alert.show();
       */
    }


}
```

/

```
/Organization class : 


import com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.annotation.Column;
import com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.annotation.PrimaryKey;
import com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.annotation.Table;
import com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.structure.BaseModel;

// **Note:** Your class must extend from BaseModel
@Table(database = MyDatabase.class)
public class Organization extends BaseModel {

    @Column
    @PrimaryKey
    int id;

    @Column
    String name;

    private Organization organization;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public void setOrganization(Organization organization) {
        this.organization = organization;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


}

    // input_dialog.xml : 

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Enter Name"
            android:id="@+id/textView"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter text here.."
            android:padding="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have changed the data you need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your `Adapter` in order to update the data in your `RecycleView`.

Set this wherever you make changes to the source data:

`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Note: As a precaution you might want to check that "adapter" is not `null`.

Comment: not working , I wrote inside  alertDialogBuilder // this code 
             if(adapter !=null){

                 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
             }

Comment: @samy I do not know what your "Organization"  class looks like and therefore I do not know what `organization.save()` does, but "organizationList" is the data source for your adapter. You are not updating the data in "organizationList" from your `AlertDialog` only "organization"!

Comment: Organization" class is class for dbflow

Comment: Please see the above I have modified the question , i add Organization" class

Comment: You need to update the data source of your `Adapter` before you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. You are not doing that.

Comment: No , but 
Now I will try then i  will  back to you

Answer (score 0):

**Add these two lines, inside your onClick of setPositiveButton**

(Just after organization.save())

```
.......
organization.save();

organizationList.add(organization);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```